# Odd "JSONObject not found" error

Tags: java, javascript, json, httprequest

I'm facing a problem regarding JSON convertion from HTTP Request body.
First, here is the Javascript code sending the request.

`object` variable can be `{"view":"global"}`, for example.

```
var sendHttpRequest = function (url, object)
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    var json = JSON.stringify(object);
    xmlhttp.send(json);
};
```

Then here is the Java part:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/departments")
public 
@ResponseBody
void getJsonObject(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    StringBuilder jb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
      BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        jb.append(line);

    } catch (Exception e) {}

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jb.toString());

    String view = json.getString("view");
    ...
}
```

The last line is raising this error :

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["view"] not found.
```

Yet, if I prints the `json` variable, I obtain `{"view":"global"}`, which seems correct...

Would anybody have any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT :**

The "not found" problem was due to the jb.toString() being passed directly to the JSONObject constructor. Here is the edited code :

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/departments")
public 
@ResponseBody
void getJsonObject(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    StringBuilder jb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
      BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        jb.append(line);

    } catch (Exception e) {}

    String str = jb.toString();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);

    String view = json.getString("view");
    ...
}
```

But this times, the error is :

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

Works with json hardcode but not with the `str` variable. Yet, its print seems correct, with no spaces :

```
{"view":"global"}
```

Comment: Did you try to reproduce this same error in a unit test or a very small console project, providing your `String` as your JSON object?

Comment: No I did not but I tried many times to replace jb.toString() by some json hardcode: JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"view\":\"global\"}");, but the same error is raised.

Comment: You're using `JSONObject` from json.org, right?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, as per execption

Comment: @user3218114 just wanted to be sure... who knows...

Comment: No problem but yes, this is org.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code as follows,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "{\"view\":\"global\"}";
    org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject(str);
    String view = json.getString("view");
    System.out.println(view);
}
```

I get

```
global
```

Comment: The same thing OP has tried, as mentioned in comments by OP.

Comment: thanks Elliott, the problem was actually due to the jb.toString() being passed directly into the JSONObject constructor ! It seems like it has be put into a variable before. However another error was just raised, "A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]". This seems quite weird since the jb.toString() print seems correct. I edited the first post.

Comment: You must be picking up some weird control character from the request. Try trimming the string. You ought to be using the Jackson library which does all this for you.

Comment: I can try to take a look to Jackson if I don't find the way but I'd like to try some more ^^ Anyway I trimmed the string but same result, it doesn't seem to contain any leading or tailing space.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `TypeReference`?

sample code:

```
TypeReference<Map<String, String>> t=new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    Map<String, String> data = mapper.readValue("{\"view\":\"global\"}", t);
    System.out.println(data.get("view")); // prints global
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("There might be some issue with the JSON string");
}
```

---

The problem might be with the encoded string that is sent from client to server. Try it again after decoding it properly.

What exactly [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) does? Print the JSON string at server side as SOP and try to debug it.

Comment: I can't test right now but I'll try tomorrow morning and share the result. Thanks !